# RichEdit not respecting PlainText with pasted content

Tags: delphi, plaintext, richedit

I create a new application, drop on a TRichedit and set the PlainText property to true. I then run the application and paste some rich formatted text into the RichEdit.

I would expect it to display as plain text however it shows the content with the formatting.

Anyone know how to use a TRichedit just as plain text (and not using a memo :))

Comment: Yes... ""To ignore the rich text information encoded in a file, set PlainText to true before streaming the text to the control. "" so I have set that to True, but not ignored. Or am I missing something :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to do the paste manually ensuring that the formatting is ignored.

```
if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT) then
  RichEdit.SelText := Clipboard.AsText;
```

<strike>Run this code from a message handler for `WM_PASTE`</strike>.

I currently do not know how to intercept the <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> keypress and replace it with this code. The `WM_PASTE` message is not sent to rich edit controls.

---

As Cody suggests in the comment, one solution is as follows:

- Make sure that all the text in the edit control is marked as protected.
- Subclass `TRichEdit` and override `CNNotify`.
- Handle the `EN_PROTECTED` message, and if `msg=WM_PASTE` then use the paste as text code above and return 1 from the message handler to indicate that the requested operation (a rich paste) is rejected.

Comment: Looks like you might be able to [handle the `EN_PROTECTED` notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250759/how-does-a-cricheditctrl-know-a-paste-operation-has-been-performed). Strange indeed that rich edit controls don't receive `WM_PASTE`. Good thing I haven't spent too much time with them.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the `OnProtectChange` event.

Comment: Or, if that's not sufficient, you could try to handle `CN_NOTIFY` in a descendant and handle cases when `NMHdr^.code = WM_PASTE`.

Comment: @TOndrej sadly the Delphi `OnProtectChange` message has lost the useful information that identifies that this is a paste as opposed to some other change.

Comment: That was my impression. In that case probably CN_NOTIFY is the easiest. I should correct my comment above, I meant `PENProtected(NMHdr)^.msg = WM_PASTE`.