# CRichEditCtrl::LimitText - problems with new lines

Tags: winapi, mfc, cricheditctrl

I have a DB text field, size 500, linked to a MFC dialog field using a `CRichEditCtrl`. I call `CRichEditCtrl::LimitText(500)` so you can't enter more text than the DB can handle and this works just fine, *until* you enter new-lines. Each new-line increases the length of the string by 2, but only counts as 1 towards the 500 limit... e.g. if I fill the edit control to the limit and have 4 new-lines, the `CString` has length 504.

I specifically want the control to only let the user enter text up to the 500 char limit, rather than truncate what they enter. How can I best achieve this? Note, I need to save the contents of the `CString` as-is, no replacing `\r\n` with `\n` in the DB or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite `OnChar`, count the number of new-lines in the text and then set `ctrl.LimitText(500 - count)`. This way you avoid busting the DBs 500 char limit.

You also have to watch for paste events which could break the limit, as described here: [How does a CRichEditCtrl know a paste operation has been performed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250759/how-does-a-cricheditctrl-know-a-paste-operation-has-been-performed)

Comment: Also need to recalculate the limit after a paste, which might have exceeded the limit itself.

Comment: Right. Didn't think of that.

Comment: Can you (or anyone) add a fix for that case?

Comment: Well, SO (as always) provides the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250759/how-does-a-cricheditctrl-know-a-paste-operation-has-been-performed

Comment: Wow, that's my question too... I worked on this code 3 years ago last! I added it to your answer for you :)